# Resigned and my one weekend off for the month was taken away

Tags: employer-relations

I'm an assistant manager for a retail store. I gave my resignation with 2 weeks' notice. My boss asked if the 2 weeks was negotiable, and I agreed that I could probably stay longer to help with the transition.

We are allowed 1 full weekend off a month and mine was scheduled towards the end of my notice. When the schedule was posted, I was on a 9 hour shift for that Saturday. I had made plans with my children for that weekend.

Any advice on how to handle this situation? I want to leave on good terms, but feel like this is a petty move on my bosses part and I definitely am less inclined to help past my 2 weeks.

Comment: Have you told them that you had already made plans that day?

Comment: How much will you work past your 2 weeks? It sounds like you said you're willing to do that, but you haven't actually agreed to it yet.

Comment: The key here is to do tackle this as soon as possible, the longer it's left, the more difficult it will be for the manager and the more likely you will be leaving on bad terms.

Comment: I'm with @JaneS on this, the first thing you need to do is ask whether they forgot that you had that day off. This could be oversight rather than petty revenge. If it's the latter then Joe's answer applies.

Answer (score 20):

> Any advice on how to handle this situation? I want to leave on good
>   terms, but feel like this is a petty move on my bosses part and I
>   definitely am less inclined to help passed my 2 weeks.

**If you really feel they are being petty, then simply refuse to change your schedule.** You can also indicate you had already planned an activity with your children and can't change it now. You can point out that you are helping them with the transition after that weekend.

If they persist in being petty, then just leave at the end of the two week period and be done with them.

You have little to lose here. If they are truly being petty, then the terms you are leaving on aren't great anyway.

Answer (score 10):

Give your boss the benefit of doubt. From your description, it sounds like the weekend off is not taken by all the employees at the same time. It is possible that your boss made a mistake in the schedule, based on a misunderstanding that you have already taken your week off for the month. Problems like those are easily solved by talking to the person involved.

It is also possible that the schedules are computer-generated, and the program made a mistake. That too, could be easily solved by talking to the person involved. Your manager should (hopefully) have enough authority to override the computer-generated schedule.

[Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor):

> Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity.

Well, not quite "stupidity" here, but more like "human error". I am inclined to believe there's no malice here, given that your boss is aware of your willingness to work beyond the notice period.

After your talk with the boss, if you find out that she was *indeed* petty, then as Joe says in his answer, do your 2 weeks notice period and be done with it.